# c++ - Boost.Log error with namespaces

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, boost-log

Trying to build the next program which use Boost::library and trying to create a new logger:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>

class TestClass
{    
     ...        
     boost::log::sources::logger lg;
};
```

My Cmake file for building this file:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)

find_package(Boost 1.63.0
             COMPONENTS system
                        filesystem
                        log
                        log_setup
                        thread
                        unit_test_framework
             REQUIRED)

include_directories(SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

file(GLOB PROJECT_SOURCES sources/*.cpp
                          sources/configuration/*.cpp)
file(GLOB PROJECT_HEADERS sources/*.h
                          sources/configuration/*.h)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
               ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
               ${PROJECT_HEADERS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
                      ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
                      Boost::log)
```

But during linking I get the next error:

```
error: 'logger' in namespace 'boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::sources' does not name a type
         boost::log::sources::logger log;
```

Why my namespace `boost::log::sources` is converted to `boost::log::v2_mt_nt5::sources`? How to solve this issue?

Comment: does it work with `Boost::log` inside `target_link_libraries`? I get an error message that it can't finde `Boost::log.lib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply missing an include directive:

```
#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>
```

Comment: Indeed. Now it works. The same file is missing in boost example.